# re-exporting module evaluates module even though export is not used

Tags: javascript, typescript

In a large typescript react app with webpack we have a common module with a bunch of utilities, classes, types etc. This module is set up with an index file that re-exports all the individual modules. Like so

```
export * from './a';
export * from './b';
export * from './c';
...
```

Some of these individual modules `a` also use a similar index file to re-export stuff, so the export tree is several layers deep. It probably involves thousands of exported items.

The issue is that when a simple function is imported from this common ui module it evaluates ALL the individual modules as well. Some of these individual modules for example have exports with expensive constructors `export const classA = new ClassA()`.

This common module is deeply ingrained through multiple apps that are quite large (think hundreds of thousands lines of code). Each individual file in our apps maybe imports at most 3 or 4 items from this common module.

Is there a way to clean this up so it is less wasteful without refactoring all the applications? Preferably without having to update all our individual import statements throughout all applications.

Comment: Perhaps you should not use expensive imports in combination with the above architecture

Comment: Or just import the full path instead to avoid this? `import thing from "./going/down/down/down.js"`

Comment: The problem is that we are talking about thousands of import statements that would need to be updated with relative import paths.